Can Stern-Gerlach experiments be conducted using nuclear spin?
If I used an element with completely paired outer electron shells, with a non-zero nuclear spin quantum number, could I conduct a nuclear Stern-Gerlach experiment?
It is known that the associated Zeeman effect has nuclear and electronic effects.
If feasible, I hope to separate an isotope of an element with a zero nuclear spin quantum number and a non-zero nuclear spin quantum number using a superconducting magnet added to the original Stern-Gerlach setup.

Theoretically, it must be possible. But the nuclear magnetic moment is already much smaller than that of electrons; it would be really difficult to resolve the differences.

@naturallyInconsistent Hopefully superconducting magnets are strong enough.

Hypothetically, the Stern-Gerlach (SG) setup could have been used to deflect Cobalt atoms using nuclear spin, if the electron magnetic dipole moment was not significantly greater than the nuclear magnetic dipole moment.
So, yes. If you have atoms whose nuclei have nonzero net spin and electrons with zero net spin (all paired), using a magnetic field stronger than that used in a typical SG setup, you should theoretically be able to carry out this experiment.

Awesome! Maybe one day I can get funding for this experiment.

Just one question. Suppose there is an element with incomplete shells, which become complete in a molecular form. If so, as nuclear spin is not reliant on electron shells, could such molecules harness nuclear effects only from elements whose electron shells as atoms are incomplete?

My personal example would be oxygen elemental vs. oxygen molecules in diamagnetic CO2.
